# Avoid repetition of aggregated column values from 2 left joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have 5 tables which contains rows like below:

**RESEARCH_REPORTS** table:

```
REPORT_ID   TOPIC
141         My Report Topic Title
142         Another Report Topic Title
143         Yet Another Report Topic Title
...
```

**PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL** table:

```
REPORT_ID    PROGRAM_AREA_ID
141          6
141          11
141          12
...
```

**PROGRAM_AREAS** table:

```
PROGRAM_AREA_ID    TITLE
6                  Program Area One
11                 Program Area Two
12                 Program Area Three
...
```

**RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORY_REL** table:

```
REPORT_ID    CATEGORY_ID
141          9
141          10
141          18
141          23
...
```

**RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORIES** table:

```
CATEGORY_ID    NAME
9              Category One
10             Category Two
18             Category Three
23             Category Four
...
```

This query is currently returning me the results from down below:

```sql
SELECT rr.report_id, 
rr.topic, 
string_agg(pa.title, '|') as program_areas, 
string_agg(rrc.name, '|') as categories 
FROM RESEARCH_REPORTS rr 
LEFT JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL parr ON rr.report_id = parr.report_id 
LEFT JOIN RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORY_REL rrcr ON rr.report_id = rrcr.report_id 
LEFT JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS pa ON parr.program_area_id = pa.program_area_id 
LEFT JOIN RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORIES rrc ON rrcr.category_id = rrc.category_id 
WHERE rr.report_id = 141
GROUP BY rr.report_id, rr.topic
```

**Query Results**:

```
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      report_id      |                topic                |                      program_areas                                                                                                                                |                                                                                     categories                                                                                                                                    |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          141        |         My Report Topic Title       |   Program Area One|Program Area Two|Program Area Three|Program Area One|Program Area Two|Program Area Three|Program Area One|Program Area Two|Program Area Three  |    Category One|Category Two|Category Three|Category Four|Category One|Category Two|Category Three|Category Four|Category One|Category Two|Category Three|Category Four|Category One|Category Two|Category Three|Category Four    |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

If noticed, the aggregated values in the result columns `program_areas` and `categories` are repeated. I need to avoid these duplicates with a select query which results in the following format:

**Preferred Query Results**:

```
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|
|      report_id      |                topic                |                      program_areas                      |                       categories                             |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|
|          141        |         My Report Topic Title       |   Program Area One|Program Area Two|Program Area Three  |    Category One|Category Two|Category Three|Category Four    |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How can I accomplish this on my current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT  rr.report_id
        , rr.topic
        , ( SELECT  string_agg(pa.title, '|')
            FROM    PROGRAM_AREAS pa
            JOIN    PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL parr
            ON      parr.program_area_id = pa.program_area_id 
            WHERE   parr.report_id = rr.report_id
            GROUP BY parr.report_id ) as program_areas
        , ( SELECT  string_agg(rrc.name, '|')
            FROM    RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORIES rrc 
            JOIN    RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORY_REL rrcr
            ON      rrcr.category_id = rrc.category_id 
            WHERE   rrcr.report_id = rr.report_id
            GROUP BY rrcr.report_id ) as categories
FROM    RESEARCH_REPORTS rr 
WHERE   rr.report_id = 141
```

I'm not sure how to set order of names/titles that get concatenated by STRING_AGG though.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT rr.report_id, rr.topic, 
STUFF((SELECT ' | '+ PROGRAM_AREAS.title FROM PROGRAM_AREAS FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS program_areas,
STUFF((SELECT ' | '+ RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORIES.NAME FROM RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORIES FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS categories
FROM RESEARCH_REPORTS rr 
LEFT JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL parr ON rr.report_id = parr.REPORT_ID 
LEFT JOIN RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORY_REL rrcr ON rr.report_id = rrcr.report_id 
WHERE rr.report_id = 141
GROUP BY rr.report_id, rr.topic
```

Comment: I've tried it. But this one returns all the available `title`s and `name`s from the PROGRAM_AREAS and RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORIES tables. If you see from my query above I'm requiring only those that are related to a RESEARCH_REPORTS record. Matched by through the PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL and RESEARCH_REPORT_CATEGORY_REL tables.